# (0, _hoc.default) is not a function. Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, high-order-component

Here is my error went create a HOC use function component instead of class Component

```
Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
    [Fri Oct 16 2020 24:17:29.696]  ERROR    TypeError: (0, _hoc.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _hoc.default)(BankingOnline)', '(0, _hoc.default)' is undefined)
    [Fri Oct 16 2020 24:17:29.696]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    [Fri Oct 16 2020 24:17:29.696]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    [Fri Oct 16 2020 24:17:29.697]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import HeaderComponent from '../../components/header';
import { StoreContext } from '../../store';
import NotAuthView from '../../components/notAuth-view'


const RequiredAuth = (Component) => props => {
    const { authFlag } = useContext(StoreContext)
    if (!authFlag) {
        return <NotAuthView />
    }

    return <Component {...props} />
}

export default RequiredAuth
```

Anybody have an idea to fix this? Thanks very much!

Comment: How are you using RequiredAuth HOC? RequiredAuth(Component)(props)?

Comment: Can you show how you use RequiredAuth?

Answer (score 0):

I has been solved this problem!
Thanks to @lissettdm and @Viet Dinh.
This is problem went i use RequiredAuth wrong way.